# Create QTreeWidget directory structure using folder path

Tags: c++, qt

In my project, I have a QFileDialog Box to select any folder. After selecting any folder, I get selected folder path. Now I want to add the selected folder and it's subfolder to QTreeWidget using the path. QTreeWidgets will show folders only, and when I will click on any folder or subfolder, all file should be shown in QTableWidgets.

Here is the code:

```
  MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
push=new QPushButton;
push->setText("Click");
connect(push,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(work()));

QIcon folderIcon(style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DirClosedIcon));
foldersTreeWidget = new QTreeWidget;
QStringList messageLabels;
messageLabels << tr("Subject") << tr("Sender") << tr("Date");
messagesTableWidget = new QTableWidget;
messagesTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(messageLabels);

messagesTableWidget->resizeColumnToContents(0);
messagesTableWidget->resizeColumnToContents(1);

rightSplitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical);
rightSplitter->addWidget(messagesTableWidget);
rightSplitter->addWidget(push);
rightSplitter->setStretchFactor(1, 1);

mainSplitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal);
mainSplitter->addWidget(foldersTreeWidget);
mainSplitter->addWidget(rightSplitter);
mainSplitter->setStretchFactor(1, 1);
setCentralWidget(mainSplitter);
}

void MainWindow::work()
{

dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                             "/home",
                                             QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                             |     QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);

QIcon folderIcon(style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DirClosedIcon));
addFolder(folderIcon, dir);
}


void MainWindow::addFolder(const QIcon &icon, const QString &name)
{

QTreeWidgetItem *root;
if (foldersTreeWidget->topLevelItemCount() == 0) {
    root = new QTreeWidgetItem(foldersTreeWidget);
    root->setText(0, tr("Mail"));
    foldersTreeWidget->setItemExpanded(root, true);
} else {
    root = foldersTreeWidget->topLevelItem(0);
}

QTreeWidgetItem *newItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(root);
newItem->setText(0, name);
newItem->setIcon(0, icon);

if (!foldersTreeWidget->currentItem())
    foldersTreeWidget->setCurrentItem(newItem);
}
```

I have not completed all the code part. The main problem is:

```
-> I am getting folder path using QFileDialog

-> I want to use the path to add folder and it's subfolders to QTreeWidgets

-> When I click on any folder in QTreeWidgets, I want to display files along with some information like (location, size, name) in QTableWidget.
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry. Now I'm trying to get QTreeView (using an underlying QFileSystemModel) to show a directory tree. If I set the RootPath to the parent directory, then I see all the children, but not the parent. I want to see parent folder and all it's subfolders.                                                                                     viewtree=new QTreeView;      dir1=new QFileSystemModel(this);    dir1->setRootPath(dir);        dir1->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot |QDir::AllDirs);         viewtree->setModel(dir1);      viewtree->setRootIndex(dir1->index(dir));

Comment: It is standard behaviour. You may fix it with `QAbstractProxyModel`, but I think that it will be too compex for you right now :)

Comment: Did you mean to say "QSortFilterProxyModel"? Thanks @Dmitry

Comment: No. You need to manuallu remap all indexes and show a single "fake" root element. I mean `QAbstractProxyModel`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html

Comment: It's very tricky for me. I really appreciate your suggestions. But, can you show me some code part. @Dmitry

Comment: No, I can't. because you want something strange. SO is not designed for help with coding ;)